# Presenting differences between Objects can be difficult when a "NewObject" change is presented

Tags: javers

I have the following:

```
    class ObjectRow
      { 
      String updated,
      String phone,
      String name, 
      String city,
      String state
      List<String> comments
      // setters/getters
      }

      class Report
      {
       String id,
       List<ObjectRow> rows
       // setters/getters
      }

      Report oldReport = getLastGeneratedReport(id);
      Report newReport = buildReport();
      String globalId;
      Diff diff = javers.compare(oldReport, newReport);
      List<ObjectRow> newReportRow = newReport.getRows();
      for (Change c : diff.getChanges())
      {
      globalId = c.getAffectedGlobalId().value;
      String rowResult = globalId.substring(globalId.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      if (!rowResult.equals(""))
         {
         int changedRow = Integer.parseInt(rowResult);
            newReportRow.get(changedRow).setUpdated(BooleanUtilsWrapper.toStringYesNo(true));
         }
      }
```

I loop through the Changes and note the difference in an Excel Spreadsheet column titled "Updated" by placing a "Yes" in that column.

For example,

```
    "Updated", "PhoneNumber", "Name", "City", "State"
```

Some rows will have the names duplicated because a row may have multiple PhoneNumbers (home, cell, work) for that same name.

```
    "Yes", 123-4567, Sally, Austin, TX
    "Yes", 123-1111, Sally, Austin, TX
    "", 234-4444, Dennis, Dallas, TX
```

This works fine as long as the number of rows are equal in both Collections (rows).

However, if I add a new row to the new Report. I have a difficult time using Change.globalId output where the indices help me in being able to notate the "Yes" in the Updated column for that row.

Javers ends up noting that all of the rows have changed when actually it was just an addition of a row which I believe is considered a "NewObject" change.

I would like to update the "Updated" column and have it compare the correct rows vs. having say like 20 rows in the old Report and 21 rows in the new Report and being off.

Is there way to prevent this from occurring? Or have you encountered something similar and can offer a suggestion?

I appreciate your assistance or any suggestions.

Comment: This question is unclear. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then try to reword your question

Comment: I attempted a reword. Please let me know if this is better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Javers report the correct row(s) that was added when comparing two objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194674/why-doesnt-javers-report-the-correct-rows-that-was-added-when-comparing-two-o)

Comment: So now you have two questions about the same issue, this one and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194674/why-doesnt-javers-report-the-correct-rows-that-was-added-when-comparing-two-o I'm confused

Comment: No worries,I think I have a fix.